# Im trying to sort a string in js. but im missing saomething

Tags: node.js

```
function sortStrings(stringList) {

    var retval = "";
    var strings = stringList.split(',');
    var sortedStrings = strings.sort((a,b) => {
                 return a < b;
                 });

    sortedStrings.forEach((str) => {
        retval = str + ',';
    } );

    return retval;
}
```

what mistake am I making

Comment: What is `stringList` and your expected output?

Comment: im re-creating my own sort ...if you pass in a list of names it should sort them

Answer (score 0):

Your `compare` function has an error. The logical operator `<` only returns either true or false while the compare is expected to return an integer. Integers `<0` mean that `a < b`, integers `=0` mean `a == b` and integers `>0` mean that `a > b`.

To accomplish that with strings, you should use localeCompare:

```
return a.localeCompare(b)
```